# Extract the k maximum elements of a list

Tags: c#, performance, linq, lambda

Let's say I have a collection of some type, e.g.

```
IEnumerable<double> values;
```

Now I need to extract the k highest values from that collection, for some parameter k. This is a very simple way to do this:

```
values.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(k)
```

However, this (if I understand this correctly) first sorts the entire list, then picks the first k elements. But if the list is very large, and k is comparatively small (smaller than log n), this is not very efficient - the list is sorted in O(n*log n), but I figure selecting the k highest values from a list should be more like O(n*k).

So, does anyone have any suggestion for a better, more efficient way to do this?

Comment: This is known as a selection algorithm. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm (it says "K smallest" but you can find the "K largest" by reversing the ordering comparison, of course). "Partial sorting" is a special case, which is more what you want: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting

Comment: Related: [Fast Algorithm for computing percentiles to remove outliers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779763/fast-algorithm-for-computing-percentiles-to-remove-outliers)

Comment: I guess another solution would be to sort it **when items are added** (instead of when accessing). That way, you avoid needing to sort it.

Comment: I nearly forgot, but +1 for realizing that `OrderBy(...).Take(...)` is inefficient. The number of times I've seen `OrderBy(...).First()` here and elsewhere is depressing. It would have been interesting if Microsoft had baked this into LINQ by making special overloads of `Take`, `First` etc. that worked on an `IOrderedEnumerable`.

Comment: It's amazing that there isn't an easy to find C# implementation of a partial sort, especially considering it's built into C++'s STL library!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This gives a bit of a performance increase. Note that it's ascending rather than descending but you should be able to repurpose it (see comments):

```
static IEnumerable<double> TopNSorted(this IEnumerable<double> source, int n)
{
    List<double> top = new List<double>(n + 1);
    using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (e.MoveNext())
                top.Add(e.Current);
            else
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Not enough elements");
        }
        top.Sort();
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            double c = e.Current;
            int index = top.BinarySearch(c);
            if (index < 0) index = ~index;
            if (index < n)                    // if (index != 0)
            {
                top.Insert(index, c);
                top.RemoveAt(n);              // top.RemoveAt(0)
            }
        }
    }
    return top;  // return ((IEnumerable<double>)top).Reverse();
}
```

Comment: Could also be an extension method to "work with LINQ" so to say.

Comment: And then it's not `O(n*k)` it's `O(n*k*k*logk)` something

Comment: @Default Whoops yes, I never bother when knocking these things together and I forgot to put it in :)

Comment: @defaultlocale ... Is that a good thing? It seems faster at selecting 50 of 10k elements but I've not really thought about the n/k behaviour. (I'd have thought `n log k` as you're making `n` binary inserts into a group of size `k`.)

Comment: @Rawling it looks like `O(n*k*logk)` so, it's close to OP's request.

Comment: @defaultlocale I tested it and it does look like you're right, now I need to figure out why :)

Comment: Yes, looks like O(n*k*logk) because of the binary search through k elements repeated at each iteration, but anyway I think you can't avoid this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, btw (and to everyone else for theirs)!

Comment: @Henrik But a binary search through `k` elements should only be `log k`, and there are `n` iterations... I still don't get where the extra factor of `k` comes from. (But from varying `k` it does look like it is there!)

Comment: @Dzienny Does the `k+` come from the updating the internal list? I was just counting comparisons, but that could be the limiting factor instead.

Comment: @Rawling Both `Insert` and `RemoveAt` are O(n) operations.

Comment: @Dzienny Yeah... I was under the impression that when measuring sorts you treated comparisons as the expensive part and discounted trivial things like shifting items about, but I guess not. Still, this doesn't explain why I'm seeing `nk logk` rather than just `nk`(The `+ logk` disappears asymptotically, right?)

Comment: Bit late but assuming that `k = wanted sorted elements` and `n = number elements in source` (usual conventions) this is `O(k + k log k + (n - k) * (log k + 2k))`. `O(k)` is the first loop. The sort is `k log k`. The later loop is run `n-k` times and does a binary search (`log k`), and add/remove a value (`2k`). Usually you get `O(n + k log k)` for this which is asymptotically better.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the below method:

```
static IEnumerable<double> GetTopValues(this IEnumerable<double> values, int count)
{
    var maxSet = new List<double>(Enumerable.Repeat(double.MinValue, count));
    var currentMin = double.MinValue;

    foreach (var t in values)
    {
        if (t <= currentMin) continue;
        maxSet.Remove(currentMin);
        maxSet.Add(t);
        currentMin = maxSet.Min();
    }

    return maxSet.OrderByDescending(i => i);
}
```

And the test program:

```
static void Main()
{
    const int SIZE = 1000000;
    const int K = 10;
    var random = new Random();

    var values = new double[SIZE];
    for (var i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        values[i] = random.NextDouble();

    // Test values
    values[SIZE/2] = 2.0;
    values[SIZE/4] = 3.0;
    values[SIZE/8] = 4.0;

    IEnumerable<double> result;

    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    stopwatch.Start();
    result = values.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(K).ToArray();
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    stopwatch.Restart();
    result = values.GetTopValues(K).ToArray();
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

On my machine results are **1002** and **14**.

Comment: @DominicKexel: Yes, but natural numbers are never negative.

Comment: @DominicKexel: I used natural numbers in order to not obscure the algorithm.

Comment: @DominicKexel: The idea is to keep max values in the list during looping through all values and then return sorted max values.

Comment: Ah, I missed that you already said it's for natural numbers only.

Comment: @DominicKexel: I transformed it to *double* with negatives and as extension method.

Comment: Will still not work: You'll have to initialize your list with `double.MinValue` instead of `0`s, e.g.: `var maxSet = new List<double>(Enumerable.Repeat(double.MinValue, count));` :-)

Comment: @DominicKexel: I missed that! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this (haven't been around C# for years, so pseudo-code it is, sorry) would be:

```
highestList = []
lowestValueOfHigh = 0
   for every item in the list
        if(lowestValueOfHigh > item) {
             delete highestList[highestList.length - 1] from list
             do insert into list with binarysearch
             if(highestList[highestList.length - 1] > lowestValueOfHigh)
                     lowestValueOfHigh = highestList[highestList.length - 1]
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't state anything about performance without profiling. In this answer I'll just try to implement `O(n*k)` take-one-enumeration-for-one-max-value approach. Personally I think that ordering approach is superior. Anyway:

```
public static IEnumerable<double> GetMaxElements(this IEnumerable<double> source)
    {
        var usedIndices = new HashSet<int>();
        while (true)
        {
            var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
            int index = 0;
            int maxIndex = 0;
            double? maxValue = null;
            while(enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                if((!maxValue.HasValue||enumerator.Current>maxValue)&&!usedIndices.Contains(index))
                {
                    maxValue = enumerator.Current;
                    maxIndex = index;
                }
                index++;
            }
            usedIndices.Add(maxIndex);
            if (!maxValue.HasValue) break;
            yield return maxValue.Value;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
var biggestElements = values.GetMaxElements().Take(3);
```

Downsides:

1. Method assumes that source IEnumerable has an order
2. Method uses additional memory/operations to save used indices.

Advantage:

- You can be sure that it takes one enumeration to get next max value.

[See it running](http://ideone.com/plJBSG)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Linqy `TopN` operator for enumerable sequences, based on the [`PriorityQueue<TElement, TPriority>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2) collection:

```
/// <summary>
/// Selects the top N elements from the source sequence. The selected elements
/// are returned in descending order.
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<T> TopN<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int n,
    IComparer<T> comparer = default)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    if (n < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(n));
    PriorityQueue<bool, T> top = new(comparer);
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (top.Count < n)
            top.Enqueue(default, item);
        else
            top.EnqueueDequeue(default, item);
    }
    List<T> topList = new(top.Count);
    while (top.TryDequeue(out _, out var item)) topList.Add(item);
    for (int i = topList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) yield return topList[i];
}
```

Usage example:

```
IEnumerable<double> topValues = values.TopN(k);
```

The `topValues` sequence contains the `k` maximum values in the `values`, in descending order. In case there are duplicate values in the `topValues`, the order of the equal values is undefined (non-stable sort).

For a [`SortedSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1)-based implementation that compiles on .NET versions earlier than .NET 6, you could look at the [5th revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72869657/5) of this answer.

An operator [`PartialSort`](https://morelinq.github.io/3.3/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_PartialSort__1_1.htm) with similar functionality exists in the [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) package. It's not implemented optimally though ([source code](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/fb9da772ffc7bd2fd01aa364de2def84df6feca2/MoreLinq/PartialSort.cs#L221)). It performs invariably a binary search for each item, instead of comparing it with the smallest item in the `top` list, resulting in many more comparisons than necessary.

Surprisingly the LINQ itself is well optimized for the [`OrderByDescending`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending)+[`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take) combination, resulting in excellent performance. It's only slightly slower than the `TopN` operator above. This applies to all versions of the .NET Core and later (.NET 5 and .NET 6). It doesn't apply to the .NET Framework platform, where the complexity is O(n*log n) as expected.

A demo that compares 4 different approaches can be found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ug2DJv). It compares:

1. `values.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(k)`.
2. `values.OrderByDescending(x => x).HideIdentity().Take(k)`, where `HideIdentity` is a trivial LINQ propagator that hides the identity of the underlying enumerable, and so it effectively disables the LINQ optimizations.
3. `values.PartialSort(k, MoreLinq.OrderByDirection.Descending)` (MoreLinq).
4. `values.TopN(k)`

Below is a typical output of the demo, running in Release mode on .NET 6:

```
.NET 6.0.0-rtm.21522.10
Extract the 100 maximum elements from 2,000,000 random values, and calculate the sum.

OrderByDescending+Take              Duration:   156 msec, Comparisons:  3,129,640, Sum: 99.997344
OrderByDescending+HideIdentity+Take Duration: 1,415 msec, Comparisons: 48,602,298, Sum: 99.997344
MoreLinq.PartialSort                Duration:   277 msec, Comparisons: 13,999,582, Sum: 99.997344
TopN                                Duration:    62 msec, Comparisons:  2,013,207, Sum: 99.997344
```

Comment: I've opened an issue on the MoreLinq GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/issues/840 "The PartialSort operator can be improved").

Comment: There is also the [SuperLinq](https://github.com/viceroypenguin/SuperLinq) library, which is a fork of MoreLinq, and has an optimized `PartialSort` implementation (particularly for string keys).