# Dictionary getting top most elements

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have created a dictionary (`differentKeys`). For getting top 2 elements I am using below code.

```
topKeys[B] = (from entry in differentKeys orderby entry.Value descending 
             select entry)
                .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value).Take(2)
                .ToDictionary(x=>x.Key,x=>x.Value).Values.ToArray();
```

But it seems not giving expected outcome. Can you please suggest line in C# which will return me top 2 maximum elements?

[image][image]

Comment: *What* is not working? What is the content of the data source, and what are the expected and the acctual results?

Comment: You are selecting values instead of keys

Comment: Actually if it is,
{46,5}
{36, 1}
{41,7}
{30, 9}
{20,4}
{26, 6}

Then I need 30, 41.

Comment: and full dictionary values are ... ?

Comment: Yasser, what you mean to say?

Comment: Your previous unedited comment mentioned only what you needed not the actual values. Hence had asked for all the dictionary values.

Comment: I am concern with top 2 or 3 values that I want comparing values of all keys

Comment: Somewhat related: [​Extract the k maximum elements of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089373/extract-the-k-maximum-elements-of-a-list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear why you keep converting to dictionaries all the time. The order of entries `Dictionary<,>` is not guaranteed.

It looks like you just want:

```
var topValues = differentKeys.Values
                             .OrderByDescending(x => x)
                             .Take(2)
                             .ToArray();
```

Or if you want the keys which correspond to the top values:

```
var keysForTopValues = differentKeys.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)
                                    .Select(x => x.Key)
                                    .Take(2)
                                    .ToArray();
```

Comment: The same issue still . See I edited my question putting snaps

Comment: @PratikK.Shah: What do you mean by "same issue"? This will give you the top two values in the dictionary. Did you actually want "the keys corresponding to the top two values"? If so, that's very different - it's important to be clear in what you're asking for.

Comment: Actually if it is, {46,5} {36, 1} {41,7} {30, 9} {20,4} {26, 6} Then I need 30, 41

Comment: @PratikK.Shah: So as I said, you want the keys corresponding to the top values. My edited answer should give you that. *Please* put more effort into writing a clear question to start with next time... and posting *text* of input and expected output is far, far better than posting screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your expected output and the actual output is, but you seem to be wanting to get top 2 from your dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, string> sample = new Dictionary<string, string>();
sample.Add("First", "Yasser");
sample.Add("Second", "Amit");
sample.Add("Third", "Sachin");
sample.Add("Fourth", "Kunal");

Dictionary<string, string> top2 = sample.Take(2).ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Value);
```

Update : Just noticed your were using "descending" in your code.

Incase you want to sort on key use this

```
sample.OrderByDescending(m => m.Key).Take(2)
```

Comment: I want maximum top 2 comparing in Values

Comment: Thanks dear, let me try, Actually need to check, complexity of code is to high so it will take some time. But thanks :)

Comment: The same issue still . See I edited my question putting snaps

Answer (score 0):

You should not keep converting to dictionaries all the time, also, what type is `differentKeys` really? I'm assuming here that it is some kind of `IEnumerable<T>`. If `differentKeys` is a `IDictionary<K,V>`, go with Jon's answers, ie use the `Values` property for the collection of values instead of selecting them via Linq.

```
topKeys[B] = (from entry in differentKeys orderby entry.Value descending 
              select entry.Value)
              .Take(2)
              .ToArray();
```