# Efficiently find the indices of the 3 highest values in an array of 5 positive integers in C#

Tags: c#, performance, sorting

There are elsewhere good discussions on sorting of 5 things, which can be done with a maximum 7 comparisons.

It should be quicker to do what I want because we don’t care about the order of the 3 biggest integers (or the 2 smallest).

Context:
My program is playing the game Splendor, traversing the game tree as fast as possible. Just prior to the code below, it has populated the

```
var GemWeight = new int[5];
```

array to decide how important each of the five coloured gems are for procurement in the current state (the three highest weighted colors will be procured).

The elements are non-negative and no greater than 127.

I am presently finding the array indices (and respective integers) of the top 3 integers with this Linq:

```
var ThreeGemsWithIndices = 
   GemWeight
  .Select((TotalWeight, ColorIndex) => new { v=TotalWeight, ColorIndex })
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.v)
  .Take(3)
  .ToArray();
```

The Visual Studio profiler says my program is spending almost 20% of the time in this Linq, so it is ripe for attack.

What is the fastest c# algorithm to find the biggest 3 numbers, not necessarily sorted, and choosing the 3rd arbitrarily if there is a tie.

Eg: From array [2,6,10,43,6] we get an array or three variables containing 1,2,3 or 4,2,3 in any order.

[N.B.: Any suggestions on speeding up the Linq within the requirement of “Top 3 unordered” are welcome, although I suspect its speed will not match an imperative solution.]

EDIT: The kind of answer I expect to be optimal would be nested if statements (with occasional swapping) as shown [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/BqZQsJPN) in C++ - perhaps some subset of this.
(I can't find the stackoverflow question which produced that answer).
I suspect the maximum needed comparisons to be 5.

Comment: any reason you are calling select infront of ordering/taking? doing select at end should already increase performance

Comment: @Rand No idea! My first ever use of Linq and I nicked it from elsewhere. So what argument do I use in the .OrderByDescending() ?

Comment: Related: [Extract the k maximum elements of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089373/extract-the-k-maximum-elements-of-a-list).

Comment: First of all, I like to cite Donald Knuth in his saying *"Premature optimization is the root of all evil"*. Even if your code spends 20% of the time in that particular section, is it *really* a performance problem? Second, if it really *is* a performance problem, you could try to get rid of LINQ and implement that 7-comparison algorithm you already found.

Comment: @derpircsher Good points. In this case I was looking for more performance because there are usually more than a billion tree nodes to be visited and at present the program does about a million per second. So I implemented the 7-compare (not the referenced one but the easier-to-read sorting network algorithm) and cut the 20% down to <3%. Very satisfying. However, I should put more focus into making smaller and smarter trees (not to mention learning about threads which can simultaneously examine separate branches utilising more of the cores at my disposal…)

Answer (score 1):

A more generic approach to be used is to go with LINQ based solution :

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] numbers = { 10, 8, 15, 7, 20 };

        var indicesOfTopThree = GetIndicesOfTopThree(numbers);

        Console.WriteLine("Indices of the top three values: " + string.Join(", ", indicesOfTopThree));
    }
    
    static int[] GetIndicesOfTopThree(int[] array)
    {
        var indices = Enumerable.Range(0, array.Length)
                                .OrderByDescending(i => array[i])
                                .Take(3)
                                .ToArray();

        return indices;
    }
}
```

> Working .NetFiddle link [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8wJoSx)

Comment: How does this differ from OP's approach? It's also just using LINQ to sort?

Answer (score 0):

1. Optimized solution to find the top 3 indices in given input.
   Time complexity is **O(n)**

   ```
   public static int[] FindTopThreeValues(int[] GemWeight)
     {
       int firstIndex = -1, secondIndex = -1, thirdIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < GemWeight.Length; i++)
        {
            if (firstIndex == -1 || GemWeight[i] > GemWeight[firstIndex])
            {
                thirdIndex = secondIndex;
                secondIndex = firstIndex;
                firstIndex = i;
            }
            else if (secondIndex == -1 || GemWeight[i] > GemWeight[secondIndex])
            {
                thirdIndex = secondIndex;
                secondIndex = i;
            }
            else if (thirdIndex == -1 || GemWeight[i] > GemWeight[thirdIndex])
            {
                thirdIndex = i;
            }
        }

   return new int[] { firstIndex, secondIndex, thirdIndex };    }
   ```

Comment: Please be aware that this approach needs up to 21 comparisons to find the top3 elements in a fixed sized array of 5 elements. That's three times the number of the optimal approach for that size

Answer (score 0):

This is a sorting network solution which sorts all 5 numbers with seven compares every time. Is there a shorter solution which satisfies the looser constraints of my question?

```
    using System;
    
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int[] numbers = new int[5]; 
    
            Console.WriteLine("Enter five integers:");
    
            // Reading integers from user input
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"Number {i + 1}: ");
                numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
    
            Sort5(numbers);
    
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe sorted numbers are:");
            foreach (int number in numbers)
                Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
    
        // Sorting method using a maximum of 7 comparisons
        static void Sort5(int[] arr)
        {
            SwapIfGreater(ref arr[0], ref arr[1]);
            SwapIfGreater(ref arr[3], ref arr[4]);
            SwapIfGreater(ref arr[0], ref arr[3]);
            SwapIfGreater(ref arr[1], ref arr[4]);
            SwapIfGreater(ref arr[1], ref arr[2]);
            SwapIfGreater(ref arr[2], ref arr[3]);
            SwapIfGreater(ref arr[1], ref arr[2]);
        }
    
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        static void Swap(ref int a, ref int b)
        {
            int temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
        }
    
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        static void SwapIfGreater(ref int a, ref int b)
        {
            if (a > b)
                Swap(ref a, ref b);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bubblesort I guess?

Comment: Sarcasm we presume...

Comment: No the name of the algorithm is [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

Comment: Bubble Sort is practically the worst performing of any sensible sorting algorithm. O(n^2). 16 comparisons in this specific case.