# Get the minimum and second minimum of this array

Tags: c#

i am trying to import data from three tow dimensional arrays and apply some calculations then to get the minimum and second minimum but i get zero as a minimum value which is not even in the values.

```
double[,] Cranelocations = { { 28.6744, 3.45 }, { 29.67, 7.25 }, { 30.67, -10.6 }, { 31.67, 11.02 }, { 32.67, 5.45 } };
double[,] Picklocation = { { 20.6744, -8.4656 }, { 21.6744, -8.4656 }, { 22.6744, -8.4656 }, { 23.6744, -8.4656 }, { 24.6744, -8.4656 }, { 25.6744, -8.4656 }, { 26.6744, -8.4656 }, { 27.6744, -8.4656 } };
double[,] Setlocation = { { 20.62, 5.03 }, { 24.28, 5.03 }, { 35.99, 14.55 }, { 19, 18.16 }, { 35.99, 5.26 }, { 40.18, 5.26 }, { 9.6, 13.16 } };
double[] Angles = new double[Cranelocations.GetLength(0) * Picklocation.GetLength(0) * Setlocation.GetLength(0)];

double Seta;

for (int i = 0; i < Cranelocations.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Picklocation.GetLength(0); j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < Setlocation.GetLength(0); k++)
        {
            double C1 = Picklocation[j, 0] - Cranelocations[i, 0];
            double V1 = Picklocation[j, 1] - Cranelocations[i, 1];
            double C2 = Setlocation[k, 0] - Cranelocations[i, 0];
            double V2 = Setlocation[k, 1] - Cranelocations[i, 1];
            double C3 = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(C1, 2) + Math.Pow(V1, 2));
            double V3 = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(C2, 2) + Math.Pow(V2, 2));

            Seta = Math.Acos(((C1 * C2) + (V1 * V2)) / (C3 * V3));
            Angles[i] = Seta * 180 / Math.PI;
            Angles[k] = Seta * 180 / Math.PI;
            Angles[j] = Seta * 180 / Math.PI;
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(Angles.Min());
```

Comment: I don't see anything in that code that attempts to get either the minimum or second minimum of anything. Code that you've not yet written clearly won't work.

Comment: Where do you define `Angles`?  How do you know there isn't a 0 in it?  When I copy/paste this exact code and define `Angles` it works just fine.  The minimum value output is `67.3864169484903`.

Comment: i just modified the code for angles clarification, and can you tell me how it get you the minimum value and the second minimum value i don't know how to code it

Comment: how did you define Angles ? and the minimum value is around 26

Comment: In case you are interested about performance, you can achieve a boost of 2x or more by using [PartialSort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078048/orderby-and-top-in-linq-with-good-performance) instead of `OrderBy`+`Take`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare the "Angles" variable at the beginning of the code along with "Seta" and "Angle".

Answer (score 0):

Your `Angles` array has *280* elements:

```
double[] Angles = new double[Cranelocations.GetLength(0) * Picklocation.GetLength(0) * Setlocation.GetLength(0)];
```

Since it's a `double[]`, none of those elements can be `null`.  So they are all `0`.  Then in your code you replace the first 8 elements of that array with other numbers.  The result is that you have an array with 272 zeros and 8 numbers greater than zero.

The smallest value in that array is 0.  The second smallest is 0.  The third smallest is 0.  And so on.

Define `Angles` using the inner dimension of your 2D arrays (the ones that are 2 elements wide).  Notice the argument to `.GetLength()`:

```
double[] Angles = new double[Cranelocations.GetLength(1) * Picklocation.GetLength(1) * Setlocation.GetLength(1)];
```

That way it would have only 8 zeros, all of which get updated in your code.  Then the minimum value would be `67.3864169484903`.

As for how to get the second minimum value, the simplest solution is probably just to sort the array and print out the first two elements.  Something like this:

```
foreach (var a in Angles.OrderBy(a => a).Take(2))
    Console.WriteLine(a);
```

Comment: I didn't get the part of the first 8 elements, plus if you tried to display the Angles array you will see that there are numbers less than 67.3864169.

Comment: @AlaaMagdy: Loop through your entire array and output it.  Or, even better, pause the debugger just after you nested loops and observe the array.  You’ll see there are many more than 8 elements, everything after the 8th element is 0, and the lowest of the first 8 elements is 67.  At this point you’re just arguing with math, and you’re wrong.  We can’t help you if you won’t even look at the results of your own code.

Comment: i am not arguing the math or anything, i am doing the same code exactly on visual studio and it gets me more numbers than the ones i saw from your link without the zeros

Comment: @AlaaMagdy: Then it seems your next step is to determine in what way the code you're using is different from the code in your question.  Because the code in your question very clearly produces the results described and demonstrated here.

Comment: it's the exact same code. The lowest numbers should be 12.933 and i get it when i display the whole array Console.wrtieline(Angles); if you did that you will find that there are 280 numbers and they are all different that means it's working good but i don't know where are zeros and why they don't show

Comment: @AlaaMagdy: Wrong again.  Observe what `Console.WriteLine(Angles);` does: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QvJ6j0  Seriously, I and everyone else in this community would like to help you.  But we can't when all you want to do is insist that your code doesn't do what it *clearly and demonstrably does do*.  Somewhere you have one or more false assumptions that you're unwilling to let go of.  We can help with code, we can't help with those assumptions.  The code you show in the question displays the value `0` for a clear and simple reason which has been explained and demonstrated ad nauseam....

Comment: @AlaaMagdy: ... If you have another question about some other code that's different from this, ask it in a new Stack Overflow question.

Comment: thanks David, i really appreciate your help and i finally was able to do it :)